# Why dose my mail lose some part of the content while being sent?

Tags: email, imap

My code sends an email with received values.

My code:

```
    self.alert = email.message.EmailMessage()
    self.alert['Subject'] = my_subject
    content1 = ''

    content2 = 'ABCDEFGHIJ1ABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJ'
    self.alert.set_content(content) #content1 or content2
    self.alert['From'] = my_from
    self.alert['To'] = my_to
    self.smtp.send_message(self.alert)
```

(content1 is six consecutive `가나다라마`.
In any reason, I cannot type it in the above code block.. The site rejects to post that. Maybe it's not English..?)

When I give `content1`, the mail of the receiver shows only some part of the content.

> 가나다라마가나다라마가나다라마가나다

On the other hand, for `content2`, even though the length is much longer than `content1`, it shows all the characters in the received email.

`content1` contains Korean.

Does the language have to do with this problem?

When I do the same thing on my Mac, it sends Korean well.

But this problem happens when I use a remote server.

Any thought is appreciated :)

Comment: What language?  What version?  This looks like python.

Comment: @Max Yes, python3.5.

Comment: @Max I got hint from your comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why, but after I tried with python3.6, the issue was gone.